# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'java.lang.String base.Utility.m3043r()'

Tags: java, android, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am a beginner in Java, and I try to use a java code from an android apk.

I am getting an error on the "m3043r()" function, here is the message I get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'java.lang.String base.Utility.m3043r()'
    at base.Utility.m3043r(Native Method)
    at base.Utility.m3040o(Utility.java:71)
    at test.test.main(test.java:6)
```

This is the java file where I get the error :

```
package base;

import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import p199z.C3411e;

public class Utility {
    
    public static String f4289b;

    public static String f4290c;

    public static final char[] f4291d = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    
    public static native byte[] bdb(String str);
    
    public static native byte[] dde(byte[] bArr, byte[] bArr2, int i);
    
    public static native String m3028dk();
    
    public static native String m3043r();
    
    public static native String m3041p();
    
    public static native byte[] en6(String str);

    public static SecretKey m3040o() {
        if (f4289b == null) {
            f4289b = new C3411e(10).mo21860j(m3027d(m3043r()));
        }
        String str = f4289b + m3050w();
        return new SecretKeySpec(str.substring(str.length() - 32).getBytes(), "AES");
    }
}
```

I shrinked the code so they are only the error appears.

It's been hours I try to find why it don't works, but I did'nt find.

I didn't implement any native library (.dll or .so), because in the original app they are only this piece of code.

Can you please tell me first what does `public static native String m3043r();` stands for, and why it don't works ?

Thanks

Comment: Nobody can tell you, from the information you have provided, what the purpose of the method `m3043r` is. This looks like [obfuscated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) code: code where variable and method names have deliberately been changed into meaningless codes to make it harder to reverse engineer.

Comment: And the error message means that this method is implemented in a native library (not written in Java) and you don't have that library when you are running your test code.